# Can you use the aspect ratio in a CSS calc computation?

Tags: css

This seems to be a simple question :

```css
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 125/100) {
  html,body,main{
    font-size: calc(0.6 * (16px + 0.03 * (100vw - 240px)));
  }
}
```

I have a kind of hacky solution to adjusting the font based on the aspect ratio. If the aspect ratio passes break points I just recalculate the font size. But I would like to do something like :

font-size : calc (aspect-ratio * simplescalingcomputation)

However if I use 100vw/100vh, well calc doesn't like that. I think the reason is that looking at the calc documentation you can't divide by px, just numbers.

Now I can do it in Javascript, I am just wondering can it be done in CSS.

Comment: What is the intended use?  Are you going to use this to render responsive `<h1>` elements and such or is this for the `<body>` text?

Comment: For responsive scaling or text and other elements.

Comment: CSS does a very good job of keeping an image's aspect ratio intact while scaling it. You can use `padding` to [scale elements while keeping the aspect ratio](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/)  There are ways to scale the font according to the screen size as well if that's what you're after. Can you create a more specific example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: The specific example was to adjust font-size by viewport width, but then if the aspect ratio was greater than a certain amount, adjust by the aspect ratio. This was to keep text from scaling too large and moving everything off page on viewports which are wide but short.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, no (apart from media queries as you realized).

There does not exist a keyword or similar for aspect-ratio in CSS. The only option you had run across would seem to work at first, but in fact the [CSS specification only allows a numeric dividend](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-syntax). I'm not sure why this is the case ─ that would be a question for the CSSWG (it's probably buried away in email archives for the curious).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment

> [...] font-size by viewport width, but then if the aspect ratio was greater than a certain amount, adjust by the aspect ratio. This was to keep text from scaling too large and moving everything off page on viewports which are wide but short.

I think the following would work. This has nothing to do with aspect ratio. This qualifies as `max-font-size` if that ever existed

1. Start with mobile screens

   You set the size of the text in relation to the screen width using `vw` units.

   This is very simple and can be done like so:

   ```css
   .logo {
     font-size: 20vw;
     text-align: center;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="logo">Stack Overflow</div>
   ```

Well, as you can already tell this works on mobile screens and scales the text well, but creates a *big* problem. The text becomes too large on big screens. My understanding is that's your main issue. A possible fix is to...

2. Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to cap font size after a given width

   The idea is that after a given screen width, the font needs to have a fixed size that's independent of the screen width. This can be achieved like so...

   ```css
   .logo {
     font-size: 20vw;
     text-align: center;
   }

   @media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
     .logo {
       font-size: 83px;
     }
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="logo">Stack Overflow</div>
   ```

The end result is that your **font will adjust to the screen size and will be responsive**.

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was doing, it just looks clunky. I was looking for a way to just do it in one calc computation by having the aspect-ratio right in the calc.